# yarn install does not trigger action

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg

I am unable to install the project. I am also not getting any error messages. After executing `yarn install` in the folder root, I don't have any messages in the console. This only happens in one project, namely in react-native-paper (https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper). I work on Windows. I use npm version 8.11.0, node v16.16.0, yarn v1.22.19.

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried only yarn instead of yarn install?

Comment: I noticed that in this folder none of yarn commend not working. For example when I type yarn -v I don't receive any information. When I go to other directory it works fine

Comment: You might not installed yarn globally. Try “npm install --global yarn” first.

Comment: I have installed it globally

Comment: Is “npm i” working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code first : npm install --global yarn
and the try to install yarn add react-native-paper

Comment: I don't want to install react-native-paper to project. I want to install it locally to make contributions

Comment: Try this guide It will be useful :- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-contribute-to-open-source-projects-beginners-guide/

Comment: this is completely unrelated to the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).